# maxima of the propagator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Given the propagator defined as $G(E) = \langle s|(H-E)^{-1}|s\rangle$. I understand that indeed you will have poles at discrete energy levels. However, when we are dealing with unstable particles it is also possible that there is a pole with nonzero imaginary part, which would manifest itself as a 'bump' at a certain energy; with a certain width.

I want to find these bumps; and the naive approach would simply be to take the derivative of G. This doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Comment: "G(E) = \langle s|(H-E)^{-1}|s\rangle" between dollar signs.

Comment: @camel - For MathJax help visit the most complete [MathJax Guide](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/278) with offsite links at the bottom covering anything not mentioned in the answer. JEB's answer is correct, my link has another answer by Nat covering brakets. In LaTeX you would use [\$\braket{0|0}\$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214728/braket-notation-in-latex) (with the appropriate add-on) but do not use LaTeX instead of MathJax in SE Q&A's (except on Tex.SE and it's Meta).